# compiling cassandra test cases failing

Tags: ant, build, cassandra

I am trying to build cassandra binaries from source and when I try to compile unit test cases, one of them fails. I am build cassandra-2.1.4 with Java 8.
These are the commands I run:

`ant -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"
ant test
ant artifacts`

Failure details:

`[junit] Testsuite: org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExportTest
    [junit] Tests run: 8, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.903 sec
    [junit] 
    [junit] ------------- Standard Output ---------------
    [junit] WARN  17:48:26 No host ID found, created eeaaa375-22f0-4a4c-845a-31decd240218 (Note: This should happen exactly once per node).
    [junit] WARN  17:48:26 No host ID found, created eeaaa375-22f0-4a4c-845a-31decd240218 (Note: This should happen exactly once per node).
    [junit] Importing 1 keys...
    [junit] 1 keys imported successfully.
    [junit] ------------- ---------------- ---------------
    [junit] Testcase: testExportColumnsWithMetadata(org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExportTest):  FAILED
    [junit] unexpected serialization format for topLevelDeletion expected:<{"[markedForDeleteAt":0,"localDeletionTime]":0}> but was:<{"[localDeletionTime":0,"markedForDeleteAt]":0}>
    [junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: unexpected serialization format for topLevelDeletion expected:<{"[markedForDeleteAt":0,"localDeletionTime]":0}> but was:<{"[localDeletionTime":0,"markedForDeleteAt]":0}>
    [junit]     at org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExportTest.testExportColumnsWithMetadata(SSTableExportTest.java:298)
    [junit] 
    [junit] 
    [junit] Test org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExportTest FAILED
    [junit] Testsuite: org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableImportTest
    [junit] Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.759 sec`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue and has been fixed in Apache Cassandra's trunk (will become 2.2) branch. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9065